# handle all exceptions and ignore

Tags: android

I create a class .This class handle all exceptions but my application stops and do nothing

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                //some code . I don't want exit
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `return`?

Comment: Is there an error shown in the Logcat?

Comment: i try return but not working.

Comment: Even if "uncaughtException" method is empty , my app be Freeze

Comment: All the examples I saw used "system.exit(0)" .but i don't want exit after caught exception.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered MyApp in manifester ?

Comment: yes. this class is working but  after caught exception my app be Freeze